# Erdos asserts about Sylvester sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, contest-math

This is an assert in the book "Problems from the book" by Titu.

Suppose the Sylvester sequence is defined by $u_1 = 2, u_{n+1} = u_n^2 - u_n + 1$, so $(u_1, u_2,...) = (2,3,7,43,...)$

Suppose there are $N$ positive integers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_N$ satisfing $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{a_i} < 1$, prove that $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{a_i} \leq \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{u_i}$

I don't find a clue about this, even I find the name of "Sylvester sequence".

Comment: It is in "Problems from the book" Ch. 8, Page 161. "Proofs from the book" is another book.

Comment: Thanks, just corrected it.

Comment: Can you find the original reference that Erdos asserted this result?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence gives the following references: Curtiss, D. R. (1922). "On Kellogg's diophantine problem". American Mathematical Monthly. 29 (10): 380–387. doi:10.2307/2299023. JSTOR 2299023; Miller, G. A. (1919). "Groups possessing a small number of sets of conjugate operators". Transactions of the American Mathematical Society. 20 (3): 260–270. doi:10.2307/1988867. JSTOR 1988867. Rosenman, Martin; Underwood, F. (1933). "Problem 3536". American Mathematical Monthly. 40 (3): 180–181. doi:10.2307/2301036. JSTOR 2301036. (continued)

Comment: (continued) Salzer, H. E. (1947). "The approximation of numbers as sums of reciprocals". American Mathematical Monthly. 54 (3): 135–142. doi:10.2307/2305906. JSTOR 2305906. MR 0020339. and Soundararajan, K. (2005). "Approximating 1 from below using n Egyptian fractions". arXiv:math.CA/0502247 (that last one is also in the answer by user EggTart).

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905659/show-sylvester-sequence-is-the-smallest-solution-with-n-terms-to-sum-of-unit-fra

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer that has been posted, or about the links I gave, Egg?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has disengaged.

Answer (score 2):

I just find this short note which is really helpful for this problem. The crucial trick here is to wisely use Muirhead inequality combining an induction.

For the proof, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0502247.pdf

The most important lemma used in the answer is the following result: if some positive number satisfies $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \dots \geq x_n, y_1 \geq y_2 \geq \dots\geq y_n$, $\Pi_{i=1}^k x_i \geq \Pi_{i=1}^k y_i$ for every $k \geq 1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$.

And the virtue of sylvester sequence is that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} = 1 - \frac{1}{\Pi_{i=1}^n a_i}$, which means that if we want $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{b_i}$ to be sufficient close to 1, then you must have a large enough $\Pi_{i=1}^n b_i$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).